# Java Program error: 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java

Recently I got a Java Challenge to get string in which Answer is Stored.I Just Work on that program from 2 Hours...I am newbie to Java and I don't exactly understand the errors coming & how to fix them Here goes the Code...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] decoded = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x14,0xA6,0x0A,0xCA,0xAD,0x6C,0x91,0x79,0x8E,0xB8,0xDE,0x91,0x30,0x5B,0xD9,0x29,0xCE,0xA5,0xEE,0x01,0x83,0xC3,0x54,0xA5,0x8D};
        b cls = new b("DarkWingDuckFTW!".getBytes());
        String ans= new String(cls.a(decoded));
    System.out.println(ans);
    }
}

class b
{
  private int[] b = new int[4];


  public b(byte[] paramArrayOfByte)
  { 
    int i=0;
    if (paramArrayOfByte == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("Error: null Key");
    if (paramArrayOfByte.length < 16)
      throw new RuntimeException("Error: Key too small");
    int j = 0;
    while (true)
    {
      if (i >= 4)
        return;
      int[] arrayOfInt = this.b;
      int k = j + 1;
      int m = 0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[j];
      int n = k + 1;
      int i1 = m | (0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[k]) << 8;
      int i2 = n + 1;
      int i3 = i1 | (0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[n]) << 16;
      j = i2 + 1;
      arrayOfInt[i] = (i3 | (0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[i2]) << 24);
      i++;
    }
  }

  void a(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int[] paramArrayOfInt, int paramInt)
  {

    paramArrayOfInt[paramInt] = 0;
    int i = 24;
    int j = 0;
    if (j >= paramArrayOfByte.length)
      return;
    paramArrayOfInt[paramInt] |= (0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[j]) << i;
    if (i == 0)
    {
      paramInt++;
      if (paramInt >= paramArrayOfInt.length)
        break label96;
      paramArrayOfInt[paramInt] = 0;
      i = 24;
    }
    while (true)
    {
      j++;
      break;
      i -= 8;
      continue;
      label96: i = 24;
    }
  }

  void a(int[] paramArrayOfInt)
  {

    int i = 1;
    if (i >= paramArrayOfInt.length)
      return;
    int j = 32;
    int k = paramArrayOfInt[i];
    int m = paramArrayOfInt[(i + 1)];
    int n = k;
    int i1 = m;
    int i2 = -957401312;
    while (true)
    {
      int i3 = j - 1;
      if (j <= 0)
      {
        paramArrayOfInt[i] = n;
        paramArrayOfInt[(i + 1)] = i1;
        i += 2;
        break;
      }
      i1 -= (n ^ (n << 4) + this.b[2]) + (i2 ^ n >>> 5) + this.b[3];
      n -= (i1 ^ (i1 << 4) + this.b[0]) + (i2 ^ i1 >>> 5) + this.b[1];
      i2 += 1640531527;
      j = i3;
    }
  }

  public byte[] a(byte[] paramArrayOfByte)
  {

    int[] arrayOfInt = new int[paramArrayOfByte.length / 4];
    a(paramArrayOfByte, arrayOfInt, 0);
    a(arrayOfInt);
    return a(arrayOfInt, 1, arrayOfInt[0]);
  }

  byte[] a(int[] paramArrayOfInt, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {

    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[paramInt2];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = paramInt1;
    while (true)
    {
      if (i >= paramInt2)
        return arrayOfByte;
      arrayOfByte[i] = ((byte)(0xFF & paramArrayOfInt[k] >> 24 - j * 8));
      j++;
      if (j == 4)
      {
        k++;
        j = 0;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Any one please fix the bugs in the program and Attach it here...

Error is

```
Main.java:57: error: undefined label: label96
            break label96;
        ^
2 errors
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Your method `a` is declared as `void` so it won't return anything and `String()` requires a parameter.

Comment: SO Which return type i can use here..

Comment: Any return type that will meet the requirements of the String constructor as explained in the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Since you're working bytes, that would be the logical assumption.

Comment: One Error is Clear and Other Error isMain.java:57: error: undefined label: label96
            break label96;
        ^
2 errors

Comment: `break` doesn't take any arguments or whatever you are passing.

Comment: I would highly suggest you familiarize yourself with the basics of Java, such as returning values, before you dive into more complex programs like this. I have no idea how a Java beginner could work all that code out and not know that void doesn't return a value and break doesn't take an argument. No offense.

Comment: @allejo One may specify a label with a break, for example to leave a set of nested loops.

Comment: @Henry I just learned something new today

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` method return type is `void`. so there is nothing to return.so you get this error message. Make your `a` method return type as `string`, `int` or etc as you need. then you can assign it to a variable and do anything you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You close curly braces of class b, and then keep defining new methods. You should declare your methods in a class definition.

Comment: This isn't even the issue.